# How to limit the characters in file name preview selected for upload?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, substring

I am using twitter bootstrap framework.
I am clicking upload button and then we select a file that need to be uploaded.Then the upload button is changed to change and name of selected file is displayed next to it.But if we are having a big file name i want to limit the file name characters to about 50.How to achieve this ?

```
<div class="span5">
        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new"
         data-provides="fileupload">
         <span class="btn btn-file" id="uploadRef"> <span class="fileupload-new">Upload
           Referral Script</span> <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
          <form:input type="file" path="refuploadScript"
           onchange="return checkFileExists();" />
         </span> <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>


          <a href="#"
          class="close fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload"
          style="float: none">x</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For doing this, first hide the default file name display span.
Then process the file name and display it separately.

So, to hide the default :

```
<span class="fileupload-preview" style="display: none;"></span>
```

on form input change , call the following script function

```
function truncatefile() // calling a function on change or select
{                           
   var fup = document.getElementById('patientupload'); //store file by ID
   var file = fup.files[0]; // store value of file
   var filePath = fup.value; 
   var name;                
   if(filePath=="")                 
   {                    
      document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML = '';                  
   }                
   else                 
   {                    
      name=filePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

      var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);//getting file extension

      var fileName = name.substring(0,name.length-4); // storing 0th position till extension begining

      var fileNameNew=""; 
      if(fileName.length > 30)  
      {
         var fileNameFst=fileName.substring(0,24); //firstpart of file
         var fileNameLst=fileName.substring(fileName.length-5,fileName.length); //last part of file
         fileNameNew=fileNameFst+ "...." + fileNameLst+"."+ext; //combine all parts         
      }         
      else
      {         
         fileNameNew=fileName+"."+ext; //if length less than 30 
      }                     
      document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML = fileNameNew;                 
   }
```